# How to add buttons to bindingnavigator through code and how to go about hiding and / or disabling the default buttons? C#

Tags: c#

Please, I am a newbie to C #. I need to add buttons through code to my BindingNavigator1.
Also, I need to know how to manipulate the enabled and visible property of buttons through code as well.
Ty.

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials in the web. Why you write here? Did you try anything?

Comment: I'm a noob in C#. I search, but I can't find anything like it.I know that I must handle a toolstripbutton, but I don't know how to connect it to the BindingNavigator.